# Locate the largest element in a multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to write a program using a method that returns the location of the largest element in a two dimensional array.

example

Enter the number of rows and columns of the array:

3 4

Enter the array:

23.5 35 2 10

4.5 3 45 3.5

35 44 5.5 9.6

the location of the largest element is at (1, 2)

I have finished my code but it isn't working. How can I fix it? All I got are the following errors:

symbol  : variable maxvalue

location: class int[]

```
                    if (a[i][j] > largest.maxvalue)
                                         ^
```

homework1a.java:51: row is already defined in locateLargest(double[][])

```
                            double row = i;
                                   ^
```

homework1a.java:52: column is already defined in locateLargest(double[][])

```
                            double column = j;
                                   ^
```

homework1a.java:53: maxValue is already defined in locateLargest(double[][])

```
                            double maxValue = a[i][j];
                                   ^
```

homework1a.java:88: i is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                             ^
```

5 errors

My code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hwm1 {

public static int[] locateLargest(double[][] a)
{

        int[] largest = new int[2];

        double row = 0;
        double column = 0;
        double maxValue = a[0][0];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
                {
                        if (a[i][j] > largest.maxvalue)
                        {
                                double row = i;
                                double column = j;
                                double maxValue = a[i][j];
                        }
                }
        }

        return largest;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
                //Create Scanner
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                //User input rows and columns
                System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns in the array: ");

                int numberOfRows = input.nextInt();
                int numberOfColumns = input.nextInt();


                //User input data in array
                System.out.println("Enter numbers into array: ");
                //Create array
                double[][] a = new double[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      {
                        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
           {
                                a[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
           }
                        int[] largest = locateLargest(a);
                        System.out.println("The location of the largest element is at "+ "("+largest[0] +", " + largest[1] + ")");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                        System.out.print(largest[i]);
           }
      }
 }
```

}

Comment: Try to follow up your questions with feedback on how far you've gone with the help you got (whether they helped you or not). And accept or upvote those you found useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the variables `row`, `column` and `maxValue` twice.

[image]

Also, in the line:

```
 if (a[i][j] > largest.maxvalue)
```

There is no such thing as `maxvalue` in your code, and neither is it a member of `largest`

In this part of your code:

[image]

Since `i` is already declared in the outer `for-loop`, you don't need to declare it again. Just use:

```
...
 for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> . You don't need to post full code below code snippet is sufficient

```
   double row = 0; //declaring first time
    double column = 0;//declaring first time 
    double maxValue = a[0][0];//declaring first time 

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
            {
                    if (a[i][j] > largest.maxvalue)// there is no variable maxvalue in Array class in java
                    {
                            double row = i; // declaring again 
                            double column = j;// declaring again 
                            double maxValue = a[i][j];// declaring again 
                    }
            }
    }

    return largest;
```

Comment: I suggest you to take go through [tour of SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and go to these link will help you in future while posting questions on Stack Overflow :  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , [Accept Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

homework1a.java:51:, homework1a.java:52:, homework1a.java:53:

For these three, remove 'double'. If you state the type when referencing the variable, Java will assume you are trying to define the variable in question. Here you already have those three defined. Additionally, since you don't use row or column at all, I suggest that you simply remove them.

homework1a.java:88: i is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

For this one, you have a nested for loop, but it uses i as well. You should use k for the second of the nested for loops (the one after the one using j).

Comment: Done, but I don't understand what you mean with "For this one, you have a nested for loop, but it uses i as well. You should use k for the second of the nested for loops (the one after the one using j)."

Comment: You have three for loops, two of which are inside the outer one. For the outer one, you use i. For the inner ones, you use j and i, respectively. For the second of the inner ones, i already exists - you are using it in the outer for loop. You should rename it something else, and k is used by convention.

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

- Loop on j should be using a[i].length
- the lines in if block is re-declaring the variables, remove the keyword 'double '
- You are not declaring setting largest anywhere so you have a logic issue
- Using a largest.maxValue is logically incorrect as it should contain the row and column number and not the actual max value

I would solve this by re-writing the code as follows which I believe is the most efficient way of achieving the goal:

```
public static int[] locateLargest(double[][] a)
{

    int maxRow=-1,maxCol=-1;
    double maxVal=-1;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] > maxVal)
            {
                maxRow = i;
                maxCol = j;
                maxVal = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return new int[]{maxRow,maxCol};
}
```

Good luck!